# Modifying salesforce reports before exporting using Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am struggling to find where to start w.r.t my following problem.

In SFDC reports, there is an "export details" button to export a user chosen report into csv or xls formats. I want to modify this xls file (for example, encrypt it) before user downloads it.
I guess I can achieve this using Apex triggers. My questions are:

1. How can I add an Apex trigger which is triggered upon a user clicking this "export details" button?
2. How can I access the xls contents in this Apex trigger code where I want to encrypt them?

I extensively searched in Apex user guide and many other sources. I can not find how to add triggers to standard SFDC buttons.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hi @Mera, there is a new stackexchange site specific to Salesforce at salesforce.stackexchange.com.  Come join the community over there! :)

Answer (score 2):

> How can I add an Apex trigger which is triggered upon a user clicking
>   this "export details" button?

This isn't currently possible.  First triggers are related to database actions and not user interface events.  You can override the behavior for a lot of buttons using a view override, but unfortunately that's also not available for report buttons.

## Workarounds

While you can't alter the behavior of the standard report experience, there is a new Reporting API that was just released by Salesforce that allows you to programmatically get the contents of a report.  Using that you could build your own "encrypted report download" tool to accomplish this.

For more information, checkout [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/14602/594) on Salesforce Stackexchange on accessing reports through the api.  And in the future, post to Salesforce Stackexchange first!! That's where the community is these days ;)

Answer (score 0):

Trigger can only be called when you do some dml operation in salesforce, clicking a button has no concern with the trigger calling,